# Extending a Laravel collection method

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

I would like to extend the Laravel `join()` method. In other words, add more functionality. Just wondering how to do it. My idea is to write my own collection class that inherits from `Illuminate\Support\Collection`. For this I have added a new Collections folder under app `(App/Collections)`. There I would add a new method `joinWithMoreFeatures()`. And from here on I don't know what to consider. My question, can someone please describe the workflow how something like this could look like?

```php
**MyCollection**
namespace App\Collections;

class MyCollection extends Collection 
{
    public function joinWithMoreFeatures($collection)
    {
    $newFilteredCollection = $collection;
        // filter 
        return $newFilteredCollection;
    }
}

**Controller**
public function index()
{
    // How i can call the joinWithMoreFeatures() function ????
    return new MyCollection(Model::all());  
}
```

Comment: "How i can call the joinWithMoreFeatures() function" ... by calling it on your Collection object you just created ...

Comment: @lagbox Thanks for the tip with the macroable. Sounds good too, but not suitable for my use case at the moment, as I want to implement more logic. A clusure seems too under-demensioned to me. What do you think?

Comment: i don't know what you mean by "under-demensioned" and why would this not provide the fuctionality you need?

Comment: @lagbox I meant that the entire logic of the new functionality cannot be built into a closure. It will amount to a separate class that is called from the collection method.

Comment: well we don't have any idea what you are doing so no one could say that to be true or not, but you have to do what fits your needs

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a new class that extends from `Collection` and then use that class to have added functionality. The `Collection` class is "macroable" which is a means to extend it at run time:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

Collection::macro('joinWithMoreFeatures', function ($collection) {
    ...
});
```

You could add this to your `AppServiceProvider`'s `boot` method or create a new Service Provider to handle this.

[Laravel 10.x Docs - Collections - Extending Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#extending-collections)

Comment: And where do you add this code? In the controller?

Comment: @MartinTTS Usually somewhere like the `AppServiceProvider`.

Comment: I explained this in the answer above and so does the documentation link ...  "You could add this to your `AppServiceProvider`'s `boot` method or create a new Service Provider to handle this."

Comment: @lagbox ok thank you for your solution approach. I will probably ask another question to make it clearer.

Comment: no problem, that is what we are here for